# retain query string after Stormpath authentication and authorization in node express site

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stormpath

I have a node express app , using express-stormpath for authentication/authorization
I have a GET route which is called with certain jquery parameters.
If the user is logged in everything is working as expected.
If not the user login screen is shown.
After stormpath authentication and authorization is done my query params are lost.
Is there any way to retain those?

```
app.get('/myRoute', stormpath.groupsRequired(['admin']), function(req, res){
    console.log('req.query ',req.query);
    //do somehting with the query data
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

after authentication req.query is `{}`.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the question, I work at [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com) and I'm more than happy to help.  Our [express-stormpath](https://github.com/stormpath/express-stormpath) library is open source, and we're always happy to fix bugs and review pull requests.

Can you tell me which version of our library you are using?  At the moment I'm not able to reproduce the problem you are seeing.  Here is a quick example that I put together with the latest version, 3.0.1:

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var stormpath = require('express-stormpath');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(stormpath.init(app));

app.get('/admins', stormpath.groupsRequired(['admins']), function(req, res){
  res.json(req.query);
});

app.on('stormpath.ready',function () {
  console.log('Stormpath Ready');
});

app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Server listening on http://localhost:' + port);
});
```

With this example, I do the following:

1.) Assert that I'm not logged in, by deleting all my cookies for localhost.

2.) Type `/admin?foo=bar` into the URL bar.

3.) I am redirected to the login page.

4.) I login with valid credentials.

5.) I am redirected to `/admins?foo=bar`, as expected, and I see the `req.query` object in the body of the page that is rendered.  This is only true if the user is in the `admins` group, if they are not I will see the "Unauthorized" error message page.

Can you compare my steps and my example to your application, and let us know if there are any differences?  Thanks!

Comment: I am using version 1.0.1 and a switch to 3.0.1 stops the project from working. No errors, just wont load. Any ideas on what to do?

Comment: I was just looking at the changelog, and it appears that this was fixed in 1.0.3, see the changelog notes [here](http://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/latest/changelog.html#version-1-0-3).  Can you try upgrading to 1.0.3?

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that stormpath is removing query from request.

But we can check it by adding middlewhare before stormpath initialization:

```
var express = require('express');
var stormpath = require('express-stormpath');

var app = express();
// binding middleware to assign req.query to req.q param
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    req.QUERY = req.query;
    next();
});

function restoreQuery(req, res, next) {
    req.query = req.QUERY;
    next();
}

app.use(stormpath.init(app, {
  // Optional configuration options.
}));

app.get('/myRoute', 
    stormpath.groupsRequired(['admin']),
    restoreQuery, 
    function(req, res){
      console.log('req.query ',req.query);
      //do somehting with the query data
      res.sendStatus(200);
    });
```

Comment: Thx for the response.In the middleware you propose the req.query is as expected.
On the route , both console.logs are empty objects {}

Comment: so You've added console.log(req.query); before next() in middleware and saw that data is as expected?

Comment: how about removing stormpath.groupsRequired(['admin']) in app.get, and comment app.use(stormpath.init()) and checking. just wanna know if stormpath is guilty or some different middleware is making this things.

Comment: by removing the stormpath.groupsRequired(['admin']) the route works as expected. So i guess it has to do with how stormpath works

Comment: I've made change to my answer, and added restoreQuery function as second middleware. Sorry I didn't find any normal workaround in this situation.

Comment: why You don't use passportjs ? (:

Comment: try to console.log(req) in Your route. maybe stormpath just replacing params.

Comment: changing stormpath is not an option!! It is still not working.. thanks for your time!

Comment: In fact You cannot change stormpath package. So better contact with stormpath support.